# How to get birthdate in existing Cognito User Pool? (Amplify iOS)

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I use AWS Amplify iOS to authorize users. I have selected gender, name and birthdate as user attributes. I would like to use Google Sign-in as one of providers so I have set Google Account and connected it to AWS Cognito. Everything like scope, app client IDs and the other stuff is set, but I get such error:

```
Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthErrorDomain Code=-3000 "(null)" UserInfo={error=invalid_request: Invalid user attributes: birthdate: String must be no longer than 10 characters
 }
```

I suppose that everything is fine, but Google Sign-in returns wrong date format so it can't intercommunicate with Cognito. How can I get it to work?
I can't create new user pool.

Answer (score 0):

You mush format the birthdate in this format "MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30265897)